# show and mark some records on top

Tags: mysql, oracle

My target DBMS's are both Oracle and MySQL

```
 SELECT
  users.*
  , hr_orders.position_label
  , hr_orders.is_boss
  , deps.label AS dep_label        -- preprocessor removes AS when using Oracle
  , users.id IN (?) AS show_on_top -- Oracle doesn't accept this IN thing
 FROM
  -- some joins here
 WHERE
  -- some filters
```

Is it possible to  give cross-DBMS equivalent of this query?

**UPDATE**

Ok, it ruins the logic, the guy before me wanted always show some users on top,

```
WHERE
    users.fake = 0
AND (
        users.id IN (?)
    OR
        -- some more detailed filters
    )
ORDER BY
    IF (users.id IN (?), 1, 2), users.label
```

where ? is parameter referring to top users.

This show_on_top field is needed to highlight top records later.

Therefore, if I move IN to where clause, only users shown on top will be selected, not the rest.

Splitting the query into two and combining users list in code still looks ugly to me.

Comment: did you try to use orm like : doctrine ?

Comment: yes, eludia ORM and it helps to run this invalid query for MySQL

Comment: You don't need to remove the AS for Oracle, its optional, not forbidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put the IN into the WHERE clause

```
SELECT
  users.*
  , hr_orders.position_label
  , hr_orders.is_boss
  , deps.label AS dep_label        
  , users.id  AS show_on_top 
 FROM
  -- some joins here
 WHERE
  -- some filters
  AND users.id IN (?,?,?)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should works:

```
WHERE users.id IN (?) AND 
  -- some filters
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me this query will not work for mysql too. You can use "IN" only in "WHERE" part of the query. In your example it is in the field list. Can you provide full query without your comments inside it?

Comment: I see `SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS users.*, users.id IN (-1,547,547,547,547) AS show_on_top` in MySQl log and there is no error. Apparently it was working by luck and I whould rewrite entire query

Comment: Hmm, I have never seen anything like this. Even if by chance mysql figures out how to process it, this syntax for sure is not portable.

Comment: I think MySQL supports a boolean, and that expression would evaluate to true/false. You could then order by it, I guess.

Comment: Quite possible. I could miss this as I am trying to keep my queries as close to SQL standard as possible to avoid portability problems.

Answer (score 0):

If you want these rows on top, rather than just these rows, you just need to put them in the ORDER BY, not in the WHERE (or in the SELECT).

Don't know whether this will work on MySQL, but it should for Oracle

```
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN users.id IN (?) then 1 else 2 end, users.label
```